Algorithm to resize controls in a windows desktop application
I have created a Windows desktop application (currently using .Net 4.8) designed in Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 on a desktop of 1920x1200, scaling 100%.  I want the code to an algorithm that correctly resizes all of the form's controls upon a dpi changed event or on a repaint event.
